# Reading a JSON file in python, reading a value and assigning it to a variable

Tags: python, json

I have a json file which looks like

```
{
        "0": {
            "id": 1700388,
            "title": "Disconnect: The Wedding Planner",
            "year": 2023,
            "imdb_id": "tt24640474",
            "tmdb_id": 1063242,
            "tmdb_type": "movie",
            "type": "movie"
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 1631017,
            "title": "The Pale Blue Eye",
            "year": 2022,
            "imdb_id": "tt14138650",
            "tmdb_id": 800815,
            "tmdb_type": "movie",
            "type": "movie"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 1597915,
            "title": "The Man from Toronto",
            "year": 2022,
            "imdb_id": "tt11671006",
            "tmdb_id": 667739,
            "tmdb_type": "movie",
            "type": "movie"
        },
```

I am trying to read this and extract the "tmbd_id" to store as a variable. I then intend to inject this into a url for an api get request.

The next step is to add the response parameters to the json file. Then adding it all into a loop. There are 1000 entries.

I have been trying to use other answers but I suspect the nature of my json is causing the issue with the integer name causing issues. It has been giving me this error

for i in data['0']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: How did `data` get defined? Your JSON value is an object, not an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json.loads` to read the file's content and then iterate to find those id's:

```py
import json

tmdb_ids = []

with open('test.json', 'r') as json_fp:
    imdb_info = json.load(json_fp)[0]

for dict_index, inner_dict in imdb_info.items():
    tmdb_ids.append(inner_dict['tmdb_id'])

print(tmdb_ids)
```

---

Result:

```
[1063242, 800815, 667739]
```

You can make it more sophisticated if you need a specific `tmdb_id` from a specific "movie" by adding some if statements to the `for` loop, choosing movies you want.

---

#### Edit

I've noticed this is an array of dictionaries, thus we can iterate over each "movie chunk" and extract the `tmdb_id` from each one:

```py
with open('test.json', 'r') as json_fp:
    imdb_info = json.load(json_fp)

tmdb_ids = [movie_info['tmdb_id'] for movies_chunk in imdb_info for movie_index, movie_info in movies_chunk.items()]
```

Comment: for dict_index, inner_dict in tmdb_info.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

This is the error running the above code..

Comment: @Thegasman2000 Sampling from the data you've given it works - but I see it isn't the full data.. could you provide it? (the full JSON and code) + I see you changed some names in my code (you're getting an error `tmdb_info.items()` I don't know what you also changed, maybe you define another variable with the same name of type list afterwards)

Comment: Sure I'm not sure whats up with the json, but as I collated it I don't doubt something is amiss. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b6d08029de942eeedac7a6b5c41de90220230120165810/3f8249 
Thanks

Comment: And sorry just. saw your edit. I changed the imdb to tmdb. Just tried fresh again, incase I missed something and same error. Thanks

Comment: @Thegasman2000 That is because the JSON starts in brackets. I've updated my code

Comment: Ah ha thank you! Yeah, the data came out the api response wonky I think. This is now giving me a list of all the ids, can I read just one at a time to add to a loop. As i will inject this into a different api url. Thanks again

Comment: @Thegasman2000 Wait, now that I see - your json contains empty dictionaries, which is not giving you the full list of `tmdb_id` - I will quickly find an answer, but if my solution is good enough tell me :)

Comment: This is working great thanks. I am able to set the first value as a variable which I can insert into the api call. Just need to figure the loop bit out but thanks so much. :)

Comment: @Thegasman2000 If you're getting stuck with it - open another question :) we will gladly help. You're welcome and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

for reading json:

```py
import json
with open("file.json","r") as file:
    text = json.load(file)
```

for tmbd_id:

```py
for i in text:
    print(text[i]["tmdb_id"])
```